# which one will give me faster good performance ,returning dataset or generic collection

Tags: asp.net

when should i return dataset and when should i return generic collection,which one will give me faster performance.Even to return generic class we have to first loop through the dataset and then add it to collection.Please help.I have read many article from internet but some say to use dataset and some say generic is fast .

Comment: Return a DataSet if you don't need  a strongly typed `List<T>`(or you don't have the class `T`) and you're using `DataAdapter.Fill(DatSet)` anyway.

Comment: The most important question you should be asking here, is which of the two approaches would be most suited to the application?  Once you've implemented that, do you have a performance issue?  Computers are really fast nowadays... a lot of people produce a lot of unnecessary code for performance gains they may not even notice.